# How to allow a column to be equal to only 1 of 3 values

Tags: mysql, constraints

Hi all while studying for `mysql` exam i came across this question in a past exam.

> Information about the distance travelled so far by each truck is no
>   longer needed. Instead we would like to store information about the
>   present status of a truck. A status can be either **Available**,
>   **Used** or **Maintained**

This status part of the question is where I'm a bit stuck. My only idea to tackle this issue would be through either a where clause or setting a string value between 4 and 9. Another idea i just had as perhaps using a check constraint?

Comment: MySQL doesn't enforce check constraints. We could create BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers. The trigger could check the value assigned to the `status` column (e.g. `IF NEW.status IN ('Available','Used','Maintained') THEN` do nothing, and allow the statement to proceed, otherwise, raise an exception to cause processing of the statement to stop. Another alternative (assuming InnoDB storage engine) is to defined a foreign key constraint to a domain table, containing the set of valid values. Then when we attempt to insert/update a row with bad value for status an error will be raised.

Comment: Why 'between 4 and 9' - that's six values?

Answer (score 1):

Move the status to a diferent table status(id, name) and store status_id in trucks as a foreign key pointing to one of these

```
status(1, 'available')
status(2, 'used')
status(3, 'maintained')
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to create a separate table containing the available status and then implement a foreign key between the `trucks` relation and the `status` relation:

```
CREATE TABLE status (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    description VARCHAR(32)
);

CREATE TABLE trucks (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    status_id INT NOT NULL,
    INDEX idx_status_id (status_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (status_id)
        REFERENCES status(id)
);
```

Some people would say to use an [ENUM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) type. However, I (and a lot of other DBA's that I have worked with) personally hate the ENUM type. Using an ENUM, you move data from where it belongs to the table metadata, updating the list is a very expensive operation, it is difficult to get all available values from your app, you can't store additional info with it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could create [`ENUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html):

> An ENUM is a string object with a value chosen from a list of permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column specification at table creation time

```
CREATE TABLE t(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  status ENUM('available','used', 'maintained')
);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2f2e1f901ff0e8d9effc11ddd7b13455)**